# Passing a function as a class field

Tags: c++

I have a class(Foo) with a function pointer(fun) as one of its fields. I'm trying to pass a pointer to another function to the class' function pointer so I'll be able to call the outer function using a class method.

```
#include <functional>


class Foo{
private:
  std::function<int(int)>* fun();   

public:
  Foo(std::function<int(int)>* fun()){
    this->fun = fun; //Error: function as left operand
  }

  void UltraFun(){
    this->fun();
  }
};

int abc(int x){
  //blah blah blah
}

int main(){
   Foo f = Foo(&abc)
}
```

Basically, abc's address should be passed as a parameter in Foo's constructor and assigned to its fun pointer to function. Therefore, whenever I call UltraFun(), abc should be called. But the error I get is in "this->fun = fun" that the left operand is a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
std::function<int(int)>* fun();
```

you declare `fun` to be a function that takes no arguments and returns a `std::function<int(int)>*`. That is probably not what you want.

What you probably want is

```
std::function<int(int)>* fun;
```

which makes `fun` a variable.

Same with the constructor argument, the argument `fun` is a function that returns a `std::function<int(int)>*`.

---

The above is only *part* of the problem... While `&abc` is indeed a pointer to a function, it can't be converted to a pointer to a `std::function<int(int)>`. But it can be used to initialize a `std::function<int(int)>` *object*.

You need to make the argument and member variable to not be pointers:

```
std::function<int(int)> fun;
```

and

```
Foo(std::function<int(int)> fun);
```

---

Lastly you don't call the function correctly, since it should take an `int` argument.

You need to pass an argument when calling it:

```
this->fun(123);  // Or some other value
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some confusion about `std::function` and function pointers.

- `std::function<int(int)> * fun();` at class scope declares a function that takes no arguments and returns a `std::function<int(int)>*`.
- `std::function<int(int)>* fun()` as a function parameter is a function pointer variable (named `fun`) that points to a function taking nothing and returning a `std::function<int(int)>*`.

Let's replace `std::function<int(int)>` with `double` for clarity:

- `double* fun();` at class scope declares a function that takes no arguments and returns a `double*`.
- `double* fun()` as a function parameter is a function pointer variable (named `fun`) that points to a function taking nothing and returning a `double*`.

But you do not need to deal with function pointers inside your class at all. `std::function` does all that for you:

```
class Foo{
private:
  std::function<int(int)> fun;   

public:
  Foo(std::function<int(int)> fun){
    this->fun = fun;
  }

  void UltraFun(){
    this->fun(1); // You must pass an integer!
  }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bW8pq8

`std::function<int(int)>` can store any function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`, you don't need to add more pointers or parentheses or even concern yourself with function pointers. And at no point in this code is it necessary to involve pointers to a `std::function`.

Note that you intend to deal with a function that *takes* an `int`, so you can't just call it without any parameters in `UltraFun`.

A more limited version without `std::function`, using function pointers directly instead:

```
class Foo{
private:
  int (*fun)(int);   

public:
  Foo(int fun(int)){
    this->fun = fun;
  }

  void UltraFun(){
    this->fun(1);
  }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/JkT9KR